# Django-CMS Will not run, 404 Page Error on initial installation

Tags: django, django-cms

I am following the tutorial here:

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/tutorial.html

I have python 2.7.2 installed and this is all in a virtualenv

my pip install list:

```
Django (1.5.1)
django-classy-tags (0.4)
django-cms (2.4.2)
django-filer (0.9.5)
django-mptt (0.5.2)
django-polymorphic (0.5.1)
django-reversion (1.7.1)
django-sekizai (0.7)
easy-thumbnails (1.3)
html5lib (1.0b2)
MySQL-python (1.2.4)
PIL (1.1.7)
six (1.3.0)
South (0.8.1)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

Project is named dcms and this folder has the contents

```
dcms manage.py media static
```

I have also included media and static folders in dcms because I was confused in which folders that they should be placed in

When I navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000 I see

```
Using the URLconf defined in dcms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^en-us/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

My urls file is a copy/paste of what is in the tutorial I posted above

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

Initially I thought maybe it is not calling the +u urlpatterns part of the code for whatever reason, but even when I delete the if statement and just have it call urlpatterns directly in the top part I still don't get the pretty splash page that should come up

any thoughts?

Comment: What do you see on http://127.0.0.1:8000/en-us/ ?

Comment: I feel like such an idiot =/  Everything comes as it should from en-us, why does it show from there?  and can I have it show from without the en-us?  My admin is even at en-us/admin which is why I just thought the whole thing was broken when I went to /admin and nothing showed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about i18 at this point.

Try using the regular `patterns`. Add this import:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
```

and replace `i18n_patterns` with regular old `patterns`.

Comment: As user bhell mentioned earlier I was able to navigate correctly using the /en-us/ tag and using just patterns and not i18n_patterns allowed me to access without having to do that.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a page?
Can you get to Admin? if so go into it and create a page at /

Comment: There is no need to create a page in a virgin django-cms install. If there is no page at / (i18n not considered), it will show a django-cms specific splash/help page.